# Getting attribute error in Python tutorial: answer = input(question.prompt) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'prompt'

Tags: python, string, attributes

I am a new and only been learning for about 10hrs during an online youtube class seen here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw&t=622s at 3hr58min. I just may got ahead of myself and need to back track and relearn fundamentals.

Multiple Choice Program

Imports a class file called Question. Prompts the user 3 questions, tracks those questions
and answers and prints a score at the end.

Error:

```
answer = input(question.prompt) ---
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'prompt'
```

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer


from Question import Question

question_prompts = [
    "what color are apples?\n(a) Red\n(b) Purple\n(c) Orange\n\n",
    "what color are bananas?\n(a) Teal\n(b) Magenta\n(c) Yellow\n\n",
    "what color are strawberries?\n(a) Yellow\n(b) Red\n(c) Blue\n\n"
]
questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
    Question(question_prompts[1], "c"),
    Question(question_prompts[2], "b"),
"""array of question objects we want to ask on our test"""
]

def run_test(questions):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question.prompt)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
    print("You got  " + str(score) + "/" + str(len(questions)) + "Correct")

run_test(questions)
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing """array of question objects we want to ask on our test""" from questions will solve the issue.

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer


from Question import Question

question_prompts = [
    "what color are apples?\n(a) Red\n(b) Purple\n(c) Orange\n\n",
    "what color are bananas?\n(a) Teal\n(b) Magenta\n(c) Yellow\n\n",
    "what color are strawberries?\n(a) Yellow\n(b) Red\n(c) Blue\n\n"
]

"""array of question objects we want to ask on our test"""
questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
    Question(question_prompts[1], "c"),
    Question(question_prompts[2], "b"),

]

def run_test(questions):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question.prompt)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
    print("You got  " + str(score) + "/" + str(len(questions)) + "Correct")

run_test(questions)
```

Comment: thanks so much, I forgot lines like these can affect the code!

Comment: Welcome to the python world

Answer (score 0):

It is because

```
questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
    Question(question_prompts[1], "c"),
    Question(question_prompts[2], "b")
]
```

The very last element of the list is a triple quote string. However, there is no instance of the `Question` class. But since it is an element of the list, python tries to fetch the instance variable `prompt`.

And it cannot find the element because there is no instance of the class.

Remove the line

Comment: wonderful, I forgot spaces like that affect the code!

Answer (score 0):

The very last element of the list is a triple quote string. However, there is no instance of the Question class. But since it is an element of the list, python tries to fetch the instance variable prompt.

And it cannot find the element because there is no instance of the class.

Remove the line

Comment: The answer is pretty much similar to mine